# Debian suddenly stopped detecting wireless networks

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I was watching youtube and suddenly my Internet conecction stopped. I checked the network and now wifi does not detect any wireless network:

[network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYF7b.png)
I've tried with wicd but doesn't detect anything either.

this is my wireless card:

```
dani@danism-debian:~$ lspci | grep Wireless
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
```

And the output of ifconfig:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::6d4:c4ff:fee6:9771  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 04:d4:c4:e6:97:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 534936  bytes 544898969 (519.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 180696  bytes 20839959 (19.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 200  bytes 15420 (15.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 200  bytes 15420 (15.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Wired conecction works though. I've tried reinstalling network-manager, but still not working.

My debian version is 10

UPDATE:

I have checked my system with lshw and the wireless card appears as UNCLAIMED. I don't know what that means, but seems to be the source of the problem:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a441c000-a441ffff

   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 15
   serial: 04:d4:c4:e6:97:71
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

Comment: Standard troubleshooting steps for any wireless any OS.  Does another device connect wirelessly to the same access point you cannot?  I always remove the wireless profiles, uninstall the network driver, restart the computer, install the newest network driver, and then try connecting with a new wireless profile

Comment: Yes. First thing I tried was reinstalling wireless driver, which is firmware-iwlwifi, as my computer's brand is asus. It did nothing. As for wireless profiles, I have never used those.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I do not think there are any other drivers for the computer that would affect this. What about updating the firmware on the router ?

Comment: It is up to date, but I dont think that's the problem, cause it doesn't detect my router or other routers, even my smartphone, whic I've been using to provide wifi to my PC for the last month.

Answer (score 0):

OK, wifi seems to be working again. I don't really know what solution gave it to me back, let me explain.

I followed the steps of diferent posts, and nothing seemed to work. I tried the commands, rebooting the system, to no result. Then again, I turned off the system, and when it started, WiFi was working again. so I don't really know which of the solutions I tried was the one that got the WiFi back. I'll post the links below so anyone looking for a similar solution:

[Page 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed)
[Page 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198373/network-unclaimed-unable-to-access-internet)

Comment: I mentioned the need to restart in my first comment. Was that a helpful answer?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, restart was needed, but it only worked after I followed the steps above. Before that I tried several reboots but nothing happened. Still appreciated nonetheless.